# Web-based RDF triplestore editor? (like phpMyAdmin for RDBs)

Tags: user-interface, rdf, semantic-web, triplestore

I'm developing a RDF database to be stored in a triple store. Visually editing the ontology is done with Protégé. However I need non-developers to be able to add records to the database.

I looked around but didn't have something that is as user-friendly as phpMyAdmin for a normal MySQL DB as an example.

Do I need to develop a visual interface for SPARQL? Or did I miss something that would allow a non-CS person to modify the records (individuals/instances not the ontology) in a graphical manner?

Update:
The best solution I found so far is to use a Semantic Media Wiki (http://semantic-mediawiki.org/) with Karima Rafes' awesome extension ([http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LinkedWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLinkedWiki)). With this, you can have users that don't know anything about RDF/Semantic Web modify data through wiki Templates and then export to RDF.

But I'm sure there is something more suitable, still looking for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the perfect tool: OntoWiki (http://aksw.org/Projects/OntoWiki.html), it matches all the criteria listed in the question. It is supposed to be back-end (triplestore) independent, but installation guidelines are given for either Virtuoso or Mysql.